# Command with 4 custom arguments, how would I parse and know if it's the correct command?

Tags: regex, vb.net, parsing, console-application

so to be more specific I'm doing this in a console application. I have a few commands like "help" that looks like this:

```
Select Case cmd 'cmd is readline

    Case "help"

        Console.WriteLine("This is the help command")

End Select
```

Showing in what way I handle my commands. Now let's say I want to add a command called "example arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4" that when executed would output the arguments in order which is specified by the user, how would I do this? I think I have read something that would solve my problem somewhere but I just can't remember where or what it was, what I tried doing was using Regex.Match() to try and read the command like so:

```
If cmd.StartsWith("example") Then
    Dim regex As Regex = New Regex("example (.*?) (.*?) (.*?) (.*?)")
    Dim match As Match = regex.Match(cmd)
    If match.Success Then
        Console.WriteLine("it worked")
    Else
        Console.WriteLine("didnt work")
    End If
End If
```

The reason why I thought this would work was because I have been doing this in the past when parsing WebClient data:

```
For Each match As Match In New Regex("this (.*?) text", RegexOptions.Singleline Or RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Matches(source)
    'the above regex says "this is text" and the match would output "is"
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups(1).Value)
Next
```

I just have no clue on how to approach this :c

Comment: you could split the string on space.  the result will be a string array of the "command" and the arguments

Comment: Or... use a pipe, split on that. In the end you need a way to split your data, thats up to you.

Comment: @Plutonix I couldn't get it to work for some reason before, fresh start of the day cleared up my mind a bit and it's working now x3 I just did `Console.WriteLine("example " & msg.Split(" ")(1) & " " & msg.Split(" ")(2) & " " & msg.Split(" ")(3) & " " & msg.Split(" ")(4))` in a Try, ended up doing what I wanted. Thanks for reminding me such a simple thing exists, lol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Console.WriteLine("example " & msg.Split(" ")(1) & " " & msg.Split(" ")(2) & " " & msg.Split(" ")(3) & " " & msg.Split(" ")(4))
```

Got it now, didn't understand how the index worked at first but was as simple as 1 = first and 2 = second etc, I feel stupid <:D